# udev weirdness: /dev/hda1 mounted but file not present

Tags: hard-disk, devices, udev

I *think* my question is related to udev and/or udisks, but I am really not sure at all what's going on here. To start with, my system works more or less fine. The less part is due to the fact that, after some upgrades to my Debian install, the /dev folder started acting weird, in relation to what I used to think I knew about unix drive management. To get to the point, here are two commands and their output:

```
$ ls /dev/h*
/dev/hidraw0  /dev/hidraw1  /dev/hidraw2  /dev/hpet

$ mount
/dev/hdb1 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=5242880,mode=755,size=5242880,mode=755)
....
```

Now, notice that `/dev/hdb1` is mounted (it really is!) but the corresponding file doesn't appear in  the `/dev` directory? How can this be? If the file doesn't exist, where is it `/dev/hdb1` listed as a link to the drive? More importantly, say I want to mount a CD. I put it in the drive, but `/dev/scd0` doesn't appear, so I can't do `mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom` because it gives me back a `File not found` error. However, after lots of fiddling I found two ways of doing it:

```
$ mount /dev/disks/by-id/ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-4160B_K3H4A7E1256
$ udisks --mount /dev/scd0 /media/cdrom
```

Both of the commands above work. So, my question is, how does `udisks` know how to deal with a device file that doesn't actually exist and, possibly more importantly, why does `mount` think it mounted the file system at `/dev/hdb1` while the file is not even there?

Finally, in case this has to do with a recent kernel upgrade:

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 3.1.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Sun Dec 11 20:40:16 UTC 2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Udisks uses its own device naming scheme. It follows the same naming rules that are normally followed by [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) (the program that manages entries in `/dev`), but it has its own implementation of these rules, it doesn't rely on the entries in `/dev`.

The entry for the root filesystem shown by `mount` is not reliable, because the root filesystem is mounted by the kernel at boot time, and boot scripts later try to fill in `/etc/mtab` (the file read by the `mount` command) but cannot know the exact device name used by the kernel (indeed, it is technically possible, even if it does not normally happen, that the device containing root filesystem has no entry in `/dev`). Check the contents of `/proc/mounts`, which queries the kernel in real time; you may see a different device name for `/` (which might not exist on your system either).

It looks like your system is missing some `udev` rules. These rules are in the `udev` package, specifically in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`. The first thing to do is make sure your `udev` package is up-to-date, as older versions of `udev` sometimes cope badly with newer kernels. And make sure that the rules file is there and undamaged.

Comment: Turns out the entry is in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/22083dc6-fef3-4134-a60a-ea862385b0d5`. All the rule files are there, last modified on Dec 4th. Deleted all the custom rules from `/etc/udev/rules.d/` that seemed to have been automatically created by something and now the CD behaves normally. Thanks!